# How to Remote Control Mac OS X with External Monitor Attached?

Tags: mac-osx, remote-desktop

Is there a VNC or remote desktop or screen sharing solution for Mac OS X that shows both the main monitor and the external monitor from the remote Mac OS X server?

On Windows boxes, I use RealVNC, and my client will have a scrollbar that enables me to see the main and second monitor screens in a single window (as long as I have "extend my desktop to this monitor" selected for the 2nd monitor on the server side).

I've tried Vines Server with various VNC clients, and none show the second monitor.

Can this be done when remote controlling an iMac with a 2nd monitor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't Apple Remote Desktop do this already? All our workstations (iMacs) have a second monitor attached, and whenever I use Remote Desktop to connect to them I can see both screens, or select which screen I want to see.

Comment: Right you are - if you mean screen sharing.
I am slightly confused (mac noob) by the naming, it seems to me that Apple Remote Desktop is a software product that must be purchased, and that screen sharing is built in (on the server side: enable Screen Sharing - use vnc://server:port on the client side).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the Mac version works exactly like the Windows version, but [LogMeIn Free](https://secure.logmein.com/products/free/features.asp) on Windows lets me view both monitors (one at a time, not scrolling).